# What do I do with the pom.xml file?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

I have just downloaded a project from github, it has a pom.xml and is missing many dependencies.

I installed `m2e Maven integration in Eclipse plugin` but now what do I do? It's installed and seems to be working but how do I download the dependencies now?

Comment: May be you can look into the docs of Maven http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on your project, run as -> maven install.

If you can't see these, you either incorrectly installed m2e, or you need to import the project as a maven project.

In that case, delete the project from your workspace (**do not** check the "delete contents on disk"). Right click in the project explorer and click on import... From that dialog, you can select existing maven projects, where you need to navigate to the highest directory containing a pom.xml file.

Also, if you have maven installed on your computer (not m2e in eclipse), you can open the directory that contains the `pom.xml` and just type `mvn clean install`. This will build your project.
If you get a "Build success" message, you'll know that the dependencies have been fetched correctly.

Comment: I started downloading for a while then I got as message "build failed" [ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format. What goes into 'goal' and 'profile' fields in the run configuration screen?

Comment: you'll be safest with `clean install` goals (you can leave `profile` empty). The `clean` part clears the cache before building, and the `install` part builds, tests and stores the compiled artifacts in your computer's local maven repository. You can see the list of goals here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 5):

- You checkout the git files to a location *different* from your Eclipse workspace.
- Start Eclipse on a clean workspace and install m2e.  (I usually install m2e-wtp to get web projects)
- Use File `->` Import `->` Existing Maven projects.
- Point to the pom.xml you want to use in the files checked out above.
- Wait while Eclipse downloads half the Internet.
- Ready.

Comment: With Eclipse 4.4 (Luna) many downloads include the m2e plugin so a separate download is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse, You have to convert your project to a maven project. right click on your project -> maven (or configure) -> convert to maven project (or enable dependencies management).

This should update your dependencies automatically, if it is not the case then right click your project -> maven -> update project (or update dependencies, it depends on the verion of m2e you are using).

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to build the project. The dependencies should be downloaded during the build.

Answer (score 0):

Pom.xml files are used for Maven projects.

Depending on your Eclipse version, maybe it's not compatible with Maven out of the box. If not, you can install a Maven plugin (like `m2e`) so that the project can be viewed as a Maven project.

Maven will do the dependency management (if pom.xml file is configured properly)

Answer (score 0):

When you right click on your project->Run As-> Maven install it will download all the dependencies that it does not have already in your local repository.